# apt update ubuntu 18.04 does not have a release file

Tags: 18.04, package-management, updates, lubuntu, ppa

When I try to query the command apt-get update, I get an error message:

```
OK:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease
OK:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                      
OK:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease              
OK:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/seafile/seafile-client/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
OK:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease            
Ign:6 https://packages.sury.org/php bionic InRelease                           
Fehl:7 https://packages.sury.org/php bionic Release                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.31.95.169 443]
Holen:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig                 
E: The archivbe "https://packages.sury.org/php bionic Release" does not have a release file.
N: Updating from such a repository cannot be done in a secure way, so it is disabled by default.
N: Weitere Details zur Erzeugung von Paketdepots sowie zu deren Benutzerkonfiguration finden Sie in der Handbuchseite apt-secure(8).
```

Comment: You need to remove the bad entry. `sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list` if in sources. If in ppa. `ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to find correct file to edit. You can just comment out with # at beginning like all the other comments. Also in Software updater, the Settings & livepatch will show you ppa in other software tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is this:

1. Go to "Software & Sources/Updates" application.
2. In the other software tab, you should see your erring PPA, which is `https://packages.sury.org/php bionic Release`
3. Remove the said entry from the sources.
4. Try the update again.

This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your repositories are set on the nearest server: go to software and update, there you can select a server (most of the times you should chose your country). check your internet and try `sudo apt dist-upgrade`